# How to see output from multiple File Watchers in JetBrains IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

I'm using JetBrains GoLand IDE however I assume the answer would be common for any JetBrains IDE such as IntelliJ etc.

I've configured file watchers for:

`go fmt`, `golint` and `go test`

`go fmt` does not have output so it works fine.

`golint` and go test both have output.  If I enable just one of them I see that output.  If I enable both I see the output of `golint` for only a split second then it is replaced by the output of `go test`  So I will never actually be able to read the output of `golint`

For now I solved this by making `go test` only display output on error, if it errors I figure I do not yet care about the output of `golint` but thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to enable `go test` as a File Watcher as the default test runner can execute on file changes.

To enable this feature, you can enable the `Toggle test auto-rerun` feature, which is the third button from top to bottom on the left side of the run test window. You can also configure the interval after which the tests run via the cog wheel.

Here's a reference for how to do this in IntelliJ IDEA, which is the same as in GoLand https://twitter.com/intellijidea/status/807239309992591361?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please vote for [WEB-14387](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14387) to be notified on any progress with it